# Problem running .net Core on Ubuntu Server

Tags: command-line, apt, application-development, ubuntu-sdk

I have created a simple console app in .net Core 2.1 and compiled the following output:

```
HelloWorld.deps.json 
HelloWorld.dll 
HelloWorld.pdb 
HelloWorld.runtimeconfig.dev.json 
HelloWorld.runtimeconfig.json
```

I have installed the .net Core SDK (link here: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/linux-package-manager/ubuntu18-04/sdk-current)

```
    user1@VMLinuxTest:~/Downloads/bin$ dotnet run HelloWorld.dll

    Couldn't find a project to run. Ensure a project exists in /home/user1/Downloads/bin, 
    or pass the path to the project using --project.
```

I'm simply trying to run the console app using the `dotnet run` command.  What am I doing wrong? (note - new to Linux so this could be a total newbie question!!)

Answer (score 1):

My bad - I've just realised that if I run the following command it works fine:

```
dotnet HelloWorld.dll
```